# How did Powershell change how it handles errors from native commands?

Tags: powershell

Between Powershell 5.1, build 17134 (Windows Version 1803) and  Powershell version 5.1, build 17763 (Windows Version 1809), something changed in how Powershell handles errors from native commands, and I am trying to understand what changed.

I have a powershell script running in an Azure pipeline on local Windows machines.  That script contains the command `git checkout origin/master`.

Starting at Windows Version 1809, this started failing.  I'd get the following error:

```
##[error]git : HEAD is now at b1e379d
##[error]At line:1 char:1
+ git checkout origin/master
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (HEAD is now at b1e379d) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.code
```

What's happening here is that the message `HEAD is now at b1e379d` is being sent to STDERR, and this is causing the NativeCommandError.  This is easy enough to work around.  I just need to call `git checkout origin/master --quiet`.

But what I'd really like to understand is what changed.  Why didn't it fail before, and why is it failing now? What are the other consequences to this change?

Comment: _"something changed in how Powershell handles errors from native commands"_ Are you sure it is PowerShell that has changed and not the git executable or something else in Windows?  Can you reproduce this difference with other native apps?

Comment: I'd like to know as well.  When in doubt, there's always sysinternals process monitor.  It works ok in cmd?  PS 6?  It's not antivirus?

Comment: Maybe related:  https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/issues/109

Comment: I'm sure that git didn't change, as my version of git didn't change.  And it's hard to tease apart Powershell vs. something else in Windows, as Powershell's version is tied to the Windows version.